# How to include & symbol in a form label and value

Tags: aura-attribute

I am trying to have a form label and value with an & symbol (see below).  I get an error.  Is there a way to do this?

```
{'label': 'M Davis & Sons Inc', 'value': 'M Davis & Sons Inc'},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` is a special character that starts an "[entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)", so you can't just use `&` anywhere. This feature of XML allows you to write characters that would otherwise break the source code (e.g. not able to compile) by using an escape sequence. In order to use a literal ampersand, you need to use `&amp;`, which will be decoded to just `&`.

## markup

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="test" type="String" default="hello &amp; goodbye" />
    {!v.test}
</aura:application>
```

## output

> hello & goodbye

Comment: That worked!  Thanks